# Swift 'Could not build Obj-C module 'BranchInvite'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, branch.io

I've been following the instructions for implementing this SDK: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-iOS-Invite-SDK... below is what I have in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'My-App' do
pod 'BranchInvite'
end
```

And here is the error I'm getting...

[image]

I've done a lot of troubleshooting to try and figure out the problem, looked at past issues of this reporsitory of this sort, and for some reason I cannot get "BranchWelcomeViewController" (nor BranchInvite) to be recognized/imported. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Do I need to populate my bridging-header?

PS: I'm using Xcode 7, Swift 2, OS X 10.10.5, and the latest version of Cocoapods.

Thanks

Comment: Did you import it in your `bridging-header` file?

Comment: With Cocoapods using frameworks you don't need to use the bridging header, and you only need to import the module you're using in the specific file you're using it in. So no, your bridging header is not the problem here. What I notice is that the compiler thinks you're missing a file, so I would check to see if that file was included in the pod that you're using

Comment: Yea it's strange - the file is there. One thing I noticed however is that all the Pod-related files+directories have question marks next to them in the left sidebar... I'm using Git and usually there's an M or A... Maybe this is something Git-related? I added cocoapods well after I started this project - or maybe something with filepaths?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

@SamYoungNY, after debugging using the project you sent over, the best approach using Swift appears to be the following:

**Podfile**

```
pod "Branch"
pod "BranchInvite"
```

**your app's bridging header**

```
#import <Branch/Branch.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchInvite.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchInviteViewController.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchInviteTextContactProvider.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchInviteEmailContactProvider.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchWelcomeView.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchWelcomeViewController.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchWelcomeControllerDelegate.h>
#import <BranchInvite/BranchWelcomeDefaultView.h>
```

Then be sure to use your project's `.xcworkspace` file if you weren't previously. Please let us know if this doesn't work. I'm happy to continue to debug with the actual project you sent over.

Answer (score 1):

I received a lot of help from @st.derrick on this question, and there was something wonky with my version control but in the end I got it working with something I found in the branch.io documentation, the answer is in this link:

https://support.branch.io/support/discussions/topics/6000008855

Comment: this link is broken.  Can you please share the solution?

Comment: sorry I don't remember what this link contained - @st.derrick can you pls assist?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but here's the archived text from that thread SamYoungNY linked to.

> If you're running into an issue where you know that you've imported >Branch, but Xcode can't seem to find it, we may know the answer. You're >probably seeing a screenshot like the one below:
>
> (Picture not archived)
>
> This likely means that you are importing Branch as a "folder reference" >and not a "group".
>
> 1. Delete the Branch folder from your project
> 2. Make sure Branch is no longer in your project's folder (in the file >system, not Xcode)
> 3. Re-import Branch and be sure to select "Create Groups" (see screenshot >below)