# Could Not Build Objective-C Module BranchInvite

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I've installed the BranchInvite framework as a pod, it's up to date. My project even recognizes, and tries to autocomplete, the module when I try to import it but the throws the error `Could Not Build Objective-C Module BranchInvite`

This post, the only one I could find, did not solve the problem as I tried to import each piece in my bridging header: [Swift 'Could not build Obj-C module 'BranchInvite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218117/swift-could-not-build-obj-c-module-branchinvite)

I've uninstalled, reinstalled the pods. No dice. I'm running Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1, is this a generic issue or what could be possible work arounds/solutions?

[image]

On a side note, I would love to not have to do all of the UI and wiring involved in sending in-app invites. I can and I will but it would be a huge time saver not to. That's one of the reasons Branch was so appealing. If there aren't any solutions are there any other deep-link services that also offer out-of-the-box UI?

Comment: I got in contact with a rep from Branch and they said that BranchInvite was not currently be supported.